# Setting UI frame does not work properly on iPhone X; works on iPhone 6s

Tags: ios, swift

I tried to dismiss my pop up view through pan gesture but the animation works in iPhone 6s iOS 13.1 but not for iPhone X iOS 13.1.3.

Below is my gesture action method : Just observe in the gif that in case of iPhone X the whole popup view bounce back and then close. This bouncing back is not desirable.

---

[image: working well gif] [image: observe bounce back behaviour as soon as remove finger]

---

```
@IBAction func panGestureRecognized(_ sender: UIPanGestureRecognizer) {
    if sender.state == .began || sender.state == .changed {
        let translation = sender.translation(in: self.view)

        baseView.center = CGPoint(x: baseView.center.x, y: baseView.center.y + translation.y)
        if baseView.frame.origin.y < CGFloat(0) {
            baseView.frame.origin.y = 0
        }
        sender.setTranslation(CGPoint.zero, in: self.view)

    } else if sender.state == .ended || sender.state == .cancelled {
        if baseView.frame.origin.y >= CGFloat(popupHeight) {
            UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.2, delay: 0, options: [.curveLinear], animations: {
                self.baseView.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: (self.window?.frame.size.height ?? 0), width: self.frame.size.width, height: self.frame.size.height)
            }, completion: { _ in
                self.removeFromSuperview()
            })
        } else {
            UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.2, delay: 0, options: [.curveLinear], animations: {
                self.baseView.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: self.frame.size.width, height: self.frame.size.height)
            }, completion: { _ in
            })
        }
    }
}
```

Also find the below popup view code UI hierarchy image and videos in both cases [ui hierarchy](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7mc1L.png).